# iMac 2011 mid WiFi working after few minutes no internet

Tags: wifi, imac

I have a problem with my iMac. 
When I connect to the WiFi it’s working, after a few minutes I don’t have internet access say: no internet.
The WiFi sign is still full, but no internet connection. 
The same WiFi working on iPhone, MacBook and any phone. I tried another networks and there worked. Any help please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Hey! Is your Wi-Fi limited to a number of users? Also try removing it from network preferences-> Wi-Fi.

Comment: Hi. The WiFi not limited for users.

Comment: I don't think this applies to an iMac, but I found today that "Private IP"—a new feature in IOS—causes iPhone 13 to say "no internet" when other devices on the same WiFi work fine.  (And MBP can ping the phone).  Apple introduced this feature with it defaulted ON.  And toggling this setting either way resets other network settings to factory default.